# How do i connect a JavaFX FXML checkbox to a MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, checkbox

I am a beginner trying to make checkboxes in a JavaFX app, can someone please tell me how do I connect to my database this checkbox method :

```
    @FXML
    private void handleOptions(ActionEvent e){
        String message= "";
        if(checkFc.isSelected()){
            message += checkFc.getText();
            return;
        }
```

i want to apply the value of the checkbox into this method :

```
public void addUsers (){    
    conn = mysqlconnect.ConnectDb();
    String sql = "insert into users (username,password,email,fc)values(?,?,?,? )";
    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, txtUsername.getText());
        pst.setString(2, txtPassword.getText());
        pst.setString(3, txtEmail.getText());
        pst.setString(4, checkFc.getText());
```

the getText method, though it works, it gets the value regardless if the checkbox is checked or not, while calling for the handleOptions method, I get cannot resolve method, which makes sense since these are prepared statements, so is there a way to make my method a preparedStatement or maybe I can connect my method another way altogether, please I really need help on this one.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do here. What do you want to set for the `fc` column if the check box is checked, and what do you want to set for the `fc` column if it's unchecked? Surely just using `if (checkFc.isSelected()) { ... }. else { ... }` in the `addUsers()` method would achieve what you want.

Comment: [mcve] please: it should demonstrate what you want to achieve and how it doesn't work as expected

Comment: @James_D if the checkbox is checked, it sets the text (or title) of the checkbox in its column, if its unchecked, its null leaving the column empty, isn't that what a checkbox does ? get a value if checked and none if unchecked, also could you elaborate, on the if statement inside the methode, cause i did and it changed nothing, may be i didn't do it correctly, i just wrote the if statement under the public void add line, ran it and nothing changed.

Comment: So just write an `if` statement inside `addUsers()` that implements that, and provides the value to set for the 4th parameter depending on whether or not the check box is selected. It's *really* unclear what the issue is.

Comment: @kleopatra i did that in another thread and no one answered, so i thought may be i should just precise exactly what i want from the code, i just want a way to connect the handleOptions method to addUsers method, where checkFc.getText loads the data in database column regardless if the checkbox is checked or not,  i want to implement a method where the data gets only loaded when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: @James_D i followed your advice and did put the if Statement inside and nothing changed, how do you set the value of the 4th parameter ? i feel like thats what i'm missing, as for the issue, i have a simple checkbox and want it to act like a checkbox,when the checkbox is checked i get the text in its respective column, when its unchecked i get an empty cell in said column, the issue is that i am getting the text all the time regardless if its checked or not.

Comment: You are already setting the 4th parameter. What do you think `pst.setString(4, ...)` does?

Comment: @James_D I know that and yet I'm still getting the checkbox text regardless if it checked or not, the if statement is not working pst.setString(4, ...) is not taking into account the if statement, can't I do a lambda?  where instead of the getText, I set it to isSelected().getText or something, I'm a beginner so I'm not sure what to do exactly.

Comment: I don't know what your problem is here. `checkBox.getText()` gets the text of the check box, regardless if it is selected or not. If you can't translate "if the check box is selected, set the 4th parameter to the text of the check box, otherwise set it to null" into code, I'm not sure anyone can help you.

Comment: OK, see my answer. But I think it's insane that you're basically asking "how do I use an `if` statement" on this site.

Comment: nobody has any intention of belittte you (and certainly not @James_D who is the nicest and most patient of all tag experts) - but it's up to __you__ and __only__ you to do the fundamental learning that enables you to understand the comments and answers. Repeating: work through basic tutorials (the javafx tag has references), practice small variations of the examples until you understand what you are doing. Then apply what you learned to your custom requirements .. starting small until it works, then increase complexity slowly. When stuck on any, of the small steps, come back with a [mcve]

Comment: _I told you I'm a beginner, you could just show me the code_ and that's exactly what this site is __not__ for .. gimmi-the-codez has no value for future readers, so it's off scope!

Comment: @kleopatra i don't want to antagonize anyone but telling a beginner " I'm not sure anyone can help you" is not qualification for nicest, though i am very grateful for helping me, his earlier advice were vague "So just write an if statement inside addUsers() that implements that" there are tons of ways to write an if statement inside a method,so figuring out that the if statement was around the 4th parameter as a beginner wasn't that obvious.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what the question is here. Why don't you just do something like

```
public void addUsers (){    
    conn = mysqlconnect.ConnectDb();
    String sql = "insert into users (username,password,email,fc)values(?,?,?,? )";
    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, txtUsername.getText());
        pst.setString(2, txtPassword.getText());
        pst.setString(3, txtEmail.getText());
        if (checkFc.isSelected()) {
            pst.setString(4, checkFc.getText());
        } else {
            pst.setString(4, null); 
            // or "" instead of null, depending on what you need
        }
        // ...
    } catch (SQLException exc) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you dude, I know how to use an if statement but just the basic if statement, i didn't think of using it that way, I apologize if it came off insanely dumb, I really looked everywhere and I'm still learning, again thank you.

Comment: @Lyly Just some advice: you won’t solve problems by looking for code, you solve them by thinking about what you want to do. I was frustrated with your comments because you appeared to be refusing to think for yourself.

Comment: I'll take that into consideration, I really tried, I tried to create an outside method like the handleOptions above and use the if statement there, I tried to do like a lambda, you might find it silly but I've racked my brain for almost a week now and nothing worked, so kinda grew frustrated and wanted it to be over with, I might have come off of just wanting the code but it was simply me not knowing of using the if statement that way and growing increasingly frustrated of nothing going my way, again thank you for your advice and thank you for your patience.